# How to display model popup at first time page load only

Tags: asp.net

I used the following code to display model popup for the first time page load,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function pageload() {
     var chkPostBack = '<%= Page.IsPostBack ? "true" : "false" %>';

     if (chkPostBack == 'false') {

         var popup = $find('ModalPopupExtender1');
         if (popup != null) {
             popup.show();
         }

     }

 }
```

I got the following error, Please help me.

```
The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to show the `ModalPopup` from codebehind `if(!Page.IsPostBack)`. Therefore you can use the `Show` method of `ModalPopupExtender`.

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
}
```

To enable it to be opened from serverside, you need to  set the `TargetControlID` of the `ModalPopupExtender` to a hidden button:

```
<asp:Button ID="Hid_ShowDialog" Style="display: none" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest performing this code from the .net code then you can do a isPostBack check, or even if you only want it once for an entire session then once you've run the JS from the .net code, set Session("ShowPopup") to false and then check against that.

Though for this problem try changing the code block to start with:

```
<%# instead of <%=
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply, i used # instead of =. now its working, but the popup is displaying every postback. i want to display it for the 1st time only

Comment: The reply above is what mine says, however it has fuller detail, check it out.